# Pentaho Kettle (Data Intergration) MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, aggregation-framework

I'm using kettle v5.2 which support the aggregation pipleline in MongoDB 
when using MongoDB input the query works for small data set but I need to use option
allowDiskUse to the query can't figure how to add this in pentaho 
while I tested this option in mongo shell and it's working as expected

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Input#MongoDBInput-queryaggpipeline

this works

```
[ {$unwind: "$friends"}, {$group : { '_id' : '$friends.id', name: {'$first': '$friends.name'} ,count: {$sum:1} } } ,{$sort: {count: -1}}, {$limit: 100} ]
```

this doesn't

```
[ {$unwind: "$friends"}, {$group : { '_id' : '$friends.id', name: {'$first': '$friends.name'} ,count: {$sum:1} } } ,{$sort: {count: -1}}, {$limit: 100} ] , {allowDiskUse: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [class who parse the pipeline](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-mongodb-plugin/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/mongo/wrapper/NoAuthMongoClientWrapper.java), you can go up to see that Pentaho use MongoDB [class java DBCollection with a deprecated function](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject...-) instead of this aggregate :

```
public Cursor aggregate(List<DBObject> pipeline,
                        AggregationOptions options)
```

So unfortunately options are not available in Pentaho Mongo Input.

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried checking the "Query is aggregation pipeline" box in the Query tab on the MongoDB input step?

Answer (score 0):

check the option "Query is aggregation pipeline"

[image: Code]